# Bukkit plugin doesn't work on server

Tags: java, plugins, server, minecraft, bukkit

When I was testing a Bukkit plugin on a local server it worked perfectly, but later on I uploaded it to an online minecraft server and this was the output it gave me:

```
16.05 20:30:55 [Multicraft] Skipped 12 lines due to rate limit (30/s)
16.05 20:30:54 [Server] INFO at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
16.05 20:30:54 [Server] INFO at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
16.05 20:30:54 [Server] INFO at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
16.05 20:30:54 [Server] INFO at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
16.05 20:30:54 [Server] INFO at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
16.05 20:30:54 [Server] INFO at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
16.05 20:30:54 [Server] INFO at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
16.05 20:30:54 [Server] INFO at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
16.05 20:30:54 [Server] INFO at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
16.05 20:30:54 [Server] INFO Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: nl/calbas/transferEnchantments/TransferEnchantments : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
16.05 20:30:54 [Server] INFO at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_80]
16.05 20:30:54 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:506) [craftbukkit-1.9.2.jar:git-Bukkit-4cb3258]
16.05 20:30:54 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:182) [craftbukkit-1.9.2.jar:git-Bukkit-4cb3258]
16.05 20:30:54 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.DedicatedPlayerList.<init>(SourceFile:14) [craftbukkit-1.9.2.jar:git-Bukkit-4cb3258]
16.05 20:30:54 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.PlayerList.<init>(PlayerList.java:69) [craftbukkit-1.9.2.jar:git-Bukkit-4cb3258]
16.05 20:30:54 [Server] INFO at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_9_R1.CraftServer.<init>(CraftServer.java:255) [craftbukkit-1.9.2.jar:git-Bukkit-4cb3258]
16.05 20:30:54 [Server] INFO at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_9_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:293) [craftbukkit-1.9.2.jar:git-Bukkit-4cb3258]
16.05 20:30:54 [Server] INFO at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:251) [craftbukkit-1.9.2.jar:git-Bukkit-4cb3258]
16.05 20:30:54 [Server] INFO at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:328) ~[craftbukkit-1.9.2.jar:git-Bukkit-4cb3258]
16.05 20:30:54 [Server] INFO at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:133) ~[craftbukkit-1.9.2.jar:git-Bukkit-4cb3258]
16.05 20:30:54 [Server] INFO org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: nl/calbas/transferEnchantments/TransferEnchantments : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
16.05 20:30:54 [Server] INFO [20:30:54 ERROR]: Could not load 'plugins/TransferEnchantments.jar' in folder 'plugins'
16.05 20:30:54 [Server] INFO [20:30:54 INFO]: This server is running CraftBukkit version git-Bukkit-4cb3258 (MC: 1.9.2) (Implementing API version 1.9.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT)
```

Does someone know what the problem might be? I could upload the code if it is helpful, but the code worked fine on my own computer.

Comment: If it worked on your computer, try to reupload the plugin and check the Java version

Comment: @Nightfighter001 I reuploaded it, but that didn't do much. And is the Java version [?:1.7.0_80]? Because that is what it writes on the 2nd to 10th line at the end.

Comment: And what version are you using to compile it? The version on the Server has to be the same or newer

Comment: I was using 7 but it was fixed by using Java 6, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://wiki.bukkit.org/Setting_Up_Your_Workspace#Which_version_of_the_JDK.3F tells you that most bukkit servers run Java 7, this means that the server you uploaded to probably does too, if you're not using JDK 7, the server will most likely not be able to load your plugin, try to download JDK 7 and compile your plugin with that instead.

Comment: Thank you, I tried Java 7 before but that didn't work. But it now works with a Java 6 compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The error states that the class it's trying to load is of version 52.0, this is the class version of Java 8.

If you see this error, it means you need to run Java 8 in order for the plugin to work. If you see version 51.0, it refers to Java 7.

To ensure you can run this plugin, you need to either update to Java 8, or submit a ticket with your hosting provider to update their Java versions to Java 8, which they should be doing due to EOL of both Java 6 and 7.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is another version of CraftBukkit/Spigot on your server, because the plugin could not find some classes. It makes a diffrence between 1.9.2 1.9.3 1.9.4 because in CraftBukkit/Spigot some classes are named diffrent. Upload your CraftBukkit/Spigot jar onto the server and try again :)

Comment: I uploaded the same craftbukkit (craftbukkit-1.9.2.jar) file and changed the name on multicraft to that jar file. It however still doesn't see the plugin. It does see an other plugin named ElytraFlight.